# Solve the following system of equations using Gaussian Elimination Method

Tags: systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Solve the following system of equations using Gaussian Elimination Method 
$$x+2y+3z=2$$
$$x+y-z=1$$
$$2x+3y+2z=3$$.

My Attempt :
$$x+2y+3z=2………(1)$$
$$x+y-z=1…………(2)$$
$$2x+3y+2z=3………(3)$$
Subtracting equation $(1)$ from equation $(2)$, we have 
$$y+4z=1………(4)$$
Multiplying equation $(1)$ by $2$ and then Subtracting from equation $(3)$, we have 
$$y+4z=1………(5)$$
Subtracting equation $(4)$ from equation $(5)$, we have 
$$0=0$$.

How do I proceed now?

Comment: You just throw out the third equation, and keep the 2 first ones. Either you conclude that there is an infinity of solutions constituting a one dimensional subspace $E$ or your instructor wants you to give details about a basis of $E$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the system:
$$x+2y+3z=2$$
$$-y-4z=-1$$
Substituting $$z=t$$ you will get $$y=1-4t$$ and $$x=2-2(1-4t)-3t$$
The system has infinity many solutions.

Comment: Is this the process of Gaussian-elimination?

Comment: Yes this is the so-called Gaussian- elimination.

Answer (score 2):

Since adding first two you are getting last one the system has infinite solutions.

From $ y=1-4z$ you get, by puting it in (2) $x =5z$. So your system has a solution $$(x,y,z) = (5t,1-4t,t)$$
where $t$ is an arbitray real number.